# How to consume non rest wcf service using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, wcf

is there any way to consume non rest WCF service using Jquery? i have wcf service which is exposed using basicHttpBinding. I would like to know if we can consume this service directly without creating proxies using svcutil.exe

Thanks,
Jagadish

Comment: You'd have to use the [jQuery.Soap plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/soap/) to call this SOAP web service ....

Comment: Do the WebGet and WebInvoke attributes make this possible? I have never tried them, but they seem promising in this situation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412172(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consume the service using `jQuery` `ajax`.
See this example, copied from a service I use:

```
// Here you define your message. You can use SOAP or VS to create a message and copy here
var soapMessage = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">.....</s:Envelope>';
$.ajax({
    // Method must be POST
    type:"POST",
    // Here you can also specify the encoding if necessary:
    contentType: "text/xml",
    url:"http://address/Service.svc/Operation",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapMessage,
    // Here you must define the contract and operation:
    headers: { "SOAPAction": "http://tempuri.org/Contract/Operation" },
    success: function(data){
        ...
    },
    error: function(request, error){
        ...
    },
});
```

If you're using old versions of jQuery, `headers` cannot be suported, you should use `beforSend` instead.